# The method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is undefined

Tags: android, android-activity, eclipse-adt

I am currently doing a tutorial series on eclipse android development and am trying to copy the code to help memorize the functionality of everything but I am getting an error for onSaveInstanceState(Bundle), it says "The method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is undefined for the type Object". I have checked to see that everything is exact multiple times but have found nothing wrong.

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
     {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, finalBill);
     }
```

Comment: where do you have the code. In activity class?

Comment: I tried your suggestion Jon but still getting the error.

Comment: Please update your question with more information about your activity. It's possible it is public instead of protected, but without knowing more we're only able to make guesses.

Comment: I figured it out... i had the void inside a private TextWatcher. All in the process of learning haha.

Comment: If you figured it out, mark Jon's answer as accepted

Comment: Sorry just new to posting stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `@Override` and ensure that your class extends`Activity`. As long as you have those two things you should be good.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override // May be public depending on the class you are extending
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putDouble(TOTAL_BILL, finalBill);
        outState.putDouble(CURRENT_TIP, tipAmount);
        outState.putDouble(BILL_WITHOUT_TIP, finalBill);

        // Wait till after you've added your items to pass the bundle
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     }
}
```

According to the [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) docs page other classes that extend `Activity` are 
[AccountAuthenticatorActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountAuthenticatorActivity.html), [ActivityGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html), [AliasActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AliasActivity.html), [ExpandableListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html), [FragmentActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), [ListActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), [NativeActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NativeActivity.html), [ActionBarActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html), [LauncherActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LauncherActivity.html), [PreferenceActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) and [TabActivity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html).

The Android sources are also a great place to look if you're trying to figure out how something works. A lot of times the notes there are a lot more descriptive about how things are implemented and what they rely on.

Ref: [core/java/android/app/Activity.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/9a7debe5857ffc7c71cfc4082b1b6d72a5cf81cd/core/java/android/app/Activity.java)

```
    /**
     * Called to retrieve per-instance state from an activity before being killed
     * so that the state can be restored in {@link #onCreate} or
     * {@link #onRestoreInstanceState} (the {@link Bundle} populated by this method
     * will be passed to both).
     *
     * <p>This method is called before an activity may be killed so that when it
     * comes back some time in the future it can restore its state.  For example,
     * if activity B is launched in front of activity A, and at some point activity
     * A is killed to reclaim resources, activity A will have a chance to save the
     * current state of its user interface via this method so that when the user
     * returns to activity A, the state of the user interface can be restored
     * via {@link #onCreate} or {@link #onRestoreInstanceState}.
     *
     * <p>Do not confuse this method with activity lifecycle callbacks such as
     * {@link #onPause}, which is always called when an activity is being placed
     * in the background or on its way to destruction, or {@link #onStop} which
     * is called before destruction.  One example of when {@link #onPause} and
     * {@link #onStop} is called and not this method is when a user navigates back
     * from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call {@link #onSaveInstanceState}
     * on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the
     * system avoids calling it.  An example when {@link #onPause} is called and
     * not {@link #onSaveInstanceState} is when activity B is launched in front of activity A:
     * the system may avoid calling {@link #onSaveInstanceState} on activity A if it isn't
     * killed during the lifetime of B since the state of the user interface of
     * A will stay intact.
     *
     * <p>The default implementation takes care of most of the UI per-instance
     * state for you by calling {@link android.view.View#onSaveInstanceState()} on each
     * view in the hierarchy that has an id, and by saving the id of the currently
     * focused view (all of which is restored by the default implementation of
     * {@link #onRestoreInstanceState}).  If you override this method to save additional
     * information not captured by each individual view, you will likely want to
     * call through to the default implementation, otherwise be prepared to save
     * all of the state of each view yourself.
     *
     * <p>If called, this method will occur before {@link #onStop}.  There are
     * no guarantees about whether it will occur before or after {@link #onPause}.
     * 
     * @param outState Bundle in which to place your saved state.
     * 
     * @see #onCreate
     * @see #onRestoreInstanceState
     * @see #onPause
     */
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putBundle(WINDOW_HIERARCHY_TAG, mWindow.saveHierarchyState());
        Parcelable p = mFragments.saveAllState();
        if (p != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(FRAGMENTS_TAG, p);
        }
        getApplication().dispatchActivitySaveInstanceState(this, outState);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` method in the right location out of the `textWatcher` method.
Just put right after the semicolon, which marks end of the `textWatcher` method.
**[};]**

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putDouble(Total_Bill, finalBill);
    outState.putDouble(Tip_Amount, tipamount);
    outState.putDouble(Bill_Without_Tip, Billbeforetip);
}
```

The error should go away.